# Replacing a column value by another column value based on regex - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is an extract of my DataFrame

```
data = [
    ['Citroën Amillis', '20 Za Des Baliveaux - 77120 Amillis', '77120', 'ok'],
    ['Relat Paris 9e', 'Métro Opéra - 75009 Paris 9e', 'Paris', 'error'],
    ['Macif Avon', '49 Av Franklin Roosevelt - 77210 Avon', '77210', 'ok'],
    ['Atac La Chapelle-la-Reine', 'Za Rue De L\'avenir - 77760 La Chapelle-la-Reine', 'La', 'error'],
    ['Société Générale La Ferté-Gaucher', '42 Rue De Paris - 77320 La Ferté-Gaucher', 'La', 'error']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nom_magasin', 'adresse', 'code_postal', 'is_code_postal'])

df
```

As you can see, there are mistakes in my dataframe. For some addresses, especially when the city name is composed (ex:"La Chapelle-la-Reine"), the column "code_postal" is wrong.

What I'm looking to do is the following: if the column "is_code_postal" is an "error", replace "code_postal" by the regex of the postal code appearing in the column "adresse".

I can't find the solution. To do I've try this `df['is_code_postal'] = np.where(df.code_postal.str.match('^[a-zA-z]'), 'error', 'ok')`. At first I was thinking about doing all changes within the same function. But I'm missing something.

And the important thing is that my dataframe is a little bit heavy (more than 250K rows) so I'd like to go for an effective solution.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: does `df['adresse'].str.extract('(\d{5})')` work for you?

Comment: Doing this ? ```df['is_code_postal'] = np.where(df.code_postal.str.match('^[a-zA-z]'), df['adresse'].str.extract('(\d{5})'), 'ok')``` @QuangHoang

Comment: `df['adresse'].str.extract('(\d{5})')` gives you the postal. You can compare those to `df['code_postal']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just ignore  the code_postal and extract it directly from 'adresse', using the code from Quang:

```
df['code_postal']=df['adresse'].str.extract('(\d{5})')
```

Comment: this would over write all postal codes, how would you apply this to only incorrect ones?

Comment: you can select only those rows via df.loc[df.is_code_postal == 'error', 'code_postal'] = df.adresse.str.extract(r'\- (\d{5})')